# Remove decimal point e.g. 99.99 = 9999

Tags: php

I am trying to find a way to remove a decimal point from a number.

E.g.

1.11 would equal 111

9.99 would equal 999

1.1111 would equal 11111

Can't seem to find the function I need to do this. I have been googling to find this function but no luck.

I have tried these functions but it is not what I am looking for:

```
floor(99.99) = 99
round(99.99) = 100
number_format(99.99) = 100
```

Comment: Convert it to a string and use `str_replace`.

Comment: Check my answer using `preg_split` if you need a solution covers local settings variations i.e 99,99

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $str = "9.99";
    echo $str = str_replace(".", "", $str);

?>
```

Output:

```
999
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use explode:

```
$num = 99.999;
$final = '';
$segments = explode($num, '.');
foreach ($segments as $segment){
  $final .= $segment;
}
echo $final;
```

Checkout this demo: http://codepad.org/DMiFNYfB

Generalizing the solution for any local settings variations we can use preg_split as follows:

```
  $num = 99.999;
    $final = '';
    $pat = "/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/";
    $segments = preg_split($pat, $num);
    foreach ($segments as $segment){
      $final .= $segment;
    }
    echo $final;
```

Also, there are another solution using for loop:

```
<?php
$num = 99.999;
$num = "$num"; //casting number to be string
$final = '';
for ($i =0; $i < strlen($num); $i++){
   if ($num[$i] == '.') continue;
   $final .= $num[$i];
}
echo $final;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to simply remove the decimal, you can just replace it.

```
str_replace('.', '', $string);
```

Comment: The downside of this answer (and all of other answers which are currently posted) is that it would make '99.99.99' become '999999' because there is no check to make sure '.' is only present once. So user input must be validated before calling str_replace on it. Other than that, the answer is nice and simple.

Answer (score 2):

You could just treat it as a string and remove the `.` character:

```
$num = str_replace ('.', '', $num);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$num = 1.11; // number 1.11
$num_to_str = strval($num); // convert number to string "1.11"
$no_decimals = str_replace(".", "", $num_to_str); // remove decimal point "111"
$str_to_num = intval($no_decimals); // convert back to number 111
```

All in one line would be something like:

```
$num_without_decimals = intval(str_replace(".", "", strval(1.11)));
```